# PEAP WPA disconnects

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, wpa2

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and everytime i connect to my university's PEAP/WPA2 wifi, it disconnects immediately. `system-ca-cert=true` was not present inside the conf file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.  I followed few solutions like inserting `system-ca-cert=true` and even changed the `password-flag` to **mypassword**. No matter what i do it is not working, any help would be really helpful.